# File manager navigation/pagination doesn't work

Tags: file-manager

I have a wierd problem with my 2.4.0 install. After I moved servers my file manager navigation/pagination (1,2,3) and the "thumbnail" option in the dropdown selection stopped working.

Clicking a navigation item just send the user to the site homepage. The URL it's trying to load is this (on hover): http://domain.com/system/C=content_publish&M=filemanager_actions&action=directory_contents&tbl_offset=15

I've tried re-uploing the entire /themes/ folder but that didn't do it. Everything else on the site is also working like it should.

I should also note that the file-uploading etc. within the window works - it's just the navigationi/pagination and "thumbnails" view that isn't.

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I have the same problem with my EE control panel. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Control Panel URL configuration may be incorrect in your config.php. You'll want to make sure the settings in the config match the URL you use to access the control panel, whether that's domain.com/system or domain.com/admin.php, etc.

Comment: I access the domain using http://domain.se/system/ and in config I have this variable $config['cp_url'] = "http://domain.se/system/index.php"; so that can't be it. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, those values should match. If you're going to domain.se/system, then cp_url should be domain.se/system

Comment: I've tried both with and without "index.php" and none of them work. It's like the ajax isn't firing on the pagination links (but everything else is working in the window except the thumbnails view). This is the link if I hover "2" in the pagination navigation "http://domain.se/system/C=content_publish&M=filemanager_actions&action=directory_contents&tbl_offset=15".